# HTML - Why z-index is not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

I've tried for some hours and this is getting on my nerves. I'm working with bootstrap and the spin.js library. I'm trying to put a color layer over an `img` tag, but this simply doesn't works.

The code which I'm working on is [this](http://jsbin.com/vararepuja/edit?html,output)

**The CSS code**

```
        .container-fluid {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .header{
            position: relative;
            max-height: 920px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .header_layer{
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: darkgrey;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        .img_header{
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 99;
        }
```

**The HTML code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header col-md-12">
        <div class="header_layer"></div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img_header">          
    </div>
</div>
```

However, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just making sure, you know that z-index goes from lowest to highest, where the lower indexes are the bottom and the higher indexes are the top

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Please paste a minium example of your code into your question. Do you realise that `z-index` only works on positioned elements?

Comment: @AndrewL, yes, I've been checking pages and pasted working examples on the same page and nothing works

Answer (score 1):

As you give `position:relative`, and `top/left : 0` so the elements do not overlap I guess you need `position:absolute`

Comment: `z-index` can work with relative also, I've checked internet before doing this question. Please check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: yes you are right but `position:relative` means left & right props of your element will be positioned from your element's original position. `left` and `top` are 0 for in your code which means they do not change the positions and do not even overlap. But in `position:absolute` case the `left` and `top` are positioned counting from parent elements 0 position. I hope this helps